# creating sitemap plugin from scratch

Tags: php, wordpress, xslt, plugins, sitemap

Hi i am creating a sitemap plugin from scratch for my client, but i didnt find any thread on google how i do that,

here below something i did but didnt worked for me:-
1> created sitemap plugin
1.1> added file index.php which contain code

```
    add_action("publish_post", "eg_create_sitemap");
    add_action("publish_page", "eg_create_sitemap");
    add_action( "save_post", "eg_create_sitemap" );
    function eg_create_sitemap() {
        if ( str_replace( '-', '', get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) ) < 10 ) {
            $tempo = '-0' . str_replace( '-', '', get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) );
        } else {
            $tempo = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
        }
        if( strlen( $tempo ) == 3 ) { $tempo = $tempo . ':00'; }
        $postsForSitemap = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'orderby'     => 'modified',
            'post_type'   => array( 'post', 'page' ),
            'order'       => 'DESC'
        ) );
        $sitemap .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="' .
            esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . 'sitemap.xsl"?>';
        $sitemap .= "\n" . '<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n";
        $sitemap .= "\t" . '<url>' . "\n" .
            "\t\t" . '<loc>' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '</loc>' .
            "\n\t\t" . '<lastmod>' . date( "Y-m-d\TH:i:s", current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) ) . $tempo . '</lastmod>' .
            "\n\t\t" . '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' .
            "\n\t\t" . '<priority>1.0</priority>' .
            "\n\t" . '</url>' . "\n";
        foreach( $postsForSitemap as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post);
            $postdate = explode( " ", $post->post_modified );
            $sitemap .= "\t" . '<url>' . "\n" .
                "\t\t" . '<loc>' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '</loc>' .
                "\n\t\t" . '<lastmod>' . $postdate[0] . 'T' . $postdate[1] . $tempo . '</lastmod>' .
                "\n\t\t" . '<changefreq>Weekly</changefreq>' .
                "\n\t\t" . '<priority>0.5</priority>' .
                "\n\t" . '</url>' . "\n";
        }
        $sitemap .= '</urlset>';
        $fp = fopen( ABSPATH . "sitemap.xml", 'w' );
        fwrite( $fp, $sitemap );
        fclose( $fp );
    }
```

and added my second file named:- sitemap-style.xsl and the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="fileType">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//sitemap:url">Sitemap</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>SitemapIndex</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$fileType='Sitemap'">Sitemap</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>Sitemap Index</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <style type="text/css">body {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:68.5%;}table {border:none;border-collapse:collapse;}table {font-size:1em;width:100%;}th {text-align:left;padding:5px;}tr.stripe {background-color:#f7f7f7;}</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>XML Sitemap By EXEIdeas</h1>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$fileType='Sitemap'"> This sitemap contains <xsl:value-of select="count(sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url)"/> URLs</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>This sitemap index contains <xsl:value-of select="count(sitemap:sitemapindex/sitemap:sitemap)"/> sitemaps</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$fileType='Sitemap'">
                            <xsl:call-template name="sitemapTable"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="siteindexTable"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="siteindexTable">
        <table cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%">URL</th>
                    <th>LastChange</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
                <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:sitemapindex/sitemap:sitemap">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 != 1">
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">stripe</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:variable name="itemURL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <a href="{$itemURL}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(sitemap:lastmod,0,11),concat(' ', substring(sitemap:lastmod,12,5)))"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sitemapTable">
        <table cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%">URL</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Change Frequency</th>
                    <th>LastChange</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
                <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 != 1">
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">stripe</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:variable name="itemURL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <a href="{$itemURL}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:if test="string(number(sitemap:priority))!='NaN'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(sitemap:priority*100,'%')"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(sitemap:changefreq, 1, 1),concat($lower, $upper),concat($upper, $lower)),substring(sitemap:changefreq, 2))"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(sitemap:lastmod,0,11),concat(' ', substring(sitemap:lastmod,12,5)))"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

after opening https://mydomain/sitemap.xml i got error this

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 5 at column 6:
> XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

any help how can i do this

Comment: i should be used

Comment: You could certainly make it much easier to read if you removed all the unnecessary  `"\n\t\t"` and instead prettyprinted the XML afterwards

Comment: "didnt worked for me" is not a great explanation. Please post expected and actual output if you want ppl to look at your code

Comment: This php-line $sitemap .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' suggest that this variable has already content. Could it be that there already was  a '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' line in that variable?